# JNA: Pointer to a pointer to a struct

Tags: pointers, struct, pass-by-reference, jna, jnaerator

I have a function call:

`long foo(mystruct **list)`

where the definition of `mystruct` is

```
typedef struct {
    otherstruct *bar[64];
} mystruct;
```

and I'm trying to get at the (JNA) Structure[] corresponding to bar. My current function definition is `int foo(PointerByReference list);` since that's what a pointer to a pointer is, but I can't figure out how to get the Structure[].

In C, the code is used as follows:

```
mystruct *list;
foo(&list);
for (i=0; i<64; i++)
    doStuff(list->bar[i]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `PointerByReference` is appropriate; use `getValue()` to get the `Pointer`
   value.
2. With that value, initialize your "mystruct" structure
3. Since "`otherstruct *bar[64]`" represents an array of `struct*`, you need to explicitly use a field of type `Structure.ByReference[]` to force JNA to treat the array as pointers instead of inlined structs.

code:

```
class OtherStruct extends Structure {
    class ByReference extends OtherStruct implements Structure.ByReference { }
    ...
}
class MyStructure extends Structure {
    public OtherStruct.ByReference[] bar = new OtherStruct.ByReference[64];
}
```

JNA should implicitly call Structure.read() and Structure.write() where necessary around native function calls, but outside of that you may need to make those calls explicitly depending on your usage.